# Combining data from multiple collections based on common field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I currently have multiple collections present in my database lets take an example of col1, col2 and col3.
These collections are based on collecting information on a user at different events and thus have different fields in their documents but there are also common ones such as full_name and email_address.
I now want to create a collection that contains the information on any of the common fields present in all the collections in the database that is in this collection the prior mentioned common data is identified and pushed into this new collection such that it acts as a common collection containing all the pushed data of prior in one place while mentioning which collection the said data is from. I'm trying to consolidate all the common data essentially and wanted to know how this could be achieved in mongodb

I've tried looking into the aggregate function but I haven't been able to find the set of functions needed to consolidate these multiple collections into one as most tend to mention only joining collections on the basis of common field. Taking input examples one by one,
col1:

```
db.col1.insertMany({
  "full_name": "Joel K",
  "email_address": "joelk@gmail.com",
  "mobile": "9343658663",
  "date": "February 5, 2022",
  "time": "11:59 AM",
  "company": "Apple Inc",
  "designation": "Manager"},
  {"full_name": "Sam K",
  "email_address": "samk@gmail.com",
  "mobile": "9343858663",
  "date": "February 7, 2022",
  "time": "09:59 AM",
  "company": "Google",
  "designation": "COO"})
```

col2:

```
db.col2.insertMany({
  "full_name": "Karan H",
  "email_address": "karanh@gmail.com",
  "mobile": "93436545323",
  "date": "February 6, 2022",
  "message": "Welcome"},
  {"full_name": "John H",
  "email_address": "john@gmail.com",
  "mobile": "9343854536",
  "date": "February 9, 2022",
  "message": "Hello"})
```

col3:

```
db.col3.insertMany({
  "full_name": "Tristan J",
  "email_address": "tristanj@gmail.com",
  "time":"03:00 PM"},
  {"full_name": "Richard S",
  "email_address": "richards@gmail.com",
  "time":"04:00 AM"})
```

Here all the fields are as strings and I want the output collection say outcol to be made consisting of the common fields between the three collections alongside the data present in that field/collection they are from so if I run a db.outcol.find() for the collection I would want the output to be:

```
{"full_name": "Joel K", "email_address": "joelk@gmail.com", "collection_name":"col1"}
{"full_name": "Sam K", "email_address": "samk@gmail.com", "collection_name":"col1"}
{"full_name": "Karan H", "email_address": "karanh@gmail.com", "collection_name":"col2"}
{"full_name": "John H", "email_address": "john@gmail.com", "collection_name":"col2"}
{"full_name": "Tristan J", "email_address": "tristanj@gmail.com", "collection_name":"col3"}
{"full_name": "Richard S", "email_address": "richards@gmail.com", "collection_name":"col3"}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data and desired result?

Comment: I've added in some sample please do let me if the operation is possible

Answer (score 0):

Would be this one:

```
db.col1.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         full_name: 1,
         email_address: 1,
         collection_name: "col1"
      }
   },
   {
      $unionWith: {
         coll: "col2",
         pipeline: [{
            $project: {
               full_name: 1,
               email_address: 1,
               collection_name: "col2"
            }
         }]
      }
   },
   {
      $unionWith: {
         coll: "col3",
         pipeline: [{
            $project: {
               full_name: 1,
               email_address: 1,
               collection_name: "col3"
            }
         }]
      }
   }
])
```

**Update**

In order to make it generic, you could use the code below. However, it will be very slow and most likely you will hit the database limitations. **Most likely it will not work in production deployment**

```
let commonFields = [];
let collections = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
for (let col of collections) {
   const allFields = db.getCollection(col).aggregate([
      { $project: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
      { $group: { _id: null, fields: { $addToSet: "$data.k" } } },
      {
         $project: {
            fields: {
               $reduce: {
                  input: "$fields",
                  initialValue: { $first: "$fields" },
                  in: { $setIntersection: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
               }
            }
         }
      },
   ]).toArray().shift().fields;
   if (commonFields.length == 0) {
      commonFields = allFields;
   } else {
      commonFields = commonFields.filter(x => allFields.includes(x));
   }
}
    
const firstCollection = collections.shift();
let project = { collection_name: firstCollection };
for (let k of commonFields)
   project[k] = 1;
let pipeline = [{ $project: project }];

for (let col of collections) {
   let project = { collection_name: col };
   for (let k of commonFields)
      project[k] = 1;

   pipeline.push({
      $unionWith: {
         coll: col,
         pipeline: [{ $project: project }]
      }
   })
}

db.getCollection(firstCollection).aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: This would be helpful for the current sample but I wanted to know if there was a case to identify the common fields among various collections and put that into a common collections when I have to perform the same on 10-20 collections

Comment: I don't think that is possible, at least not with a single aggregation pipeline. You would need to loop over all collections, gather common fields and then compose the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: While using the code I'm getting an error of cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'fields') how should I fix this?

Comment: I guess one of your collections is empty. Add condition `if (db.getCollection(col).countDocuments() > 0)`